# ListView items repeating

Tags: android, android-listview

I know this question has been asked before and I have tried those solutions but it didn't help. Items keep repeating after the 9th item. Here is my code.

```
@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.tile_company, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.companyname);
        holder.type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.companytype);
        holder.logo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        holder.category = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category);
        holder.distance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.distance);
        holder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

        new GetDistanceTime().execute(LocateOutlets.userLatlng, companyList.get(position).getCompanyLatLng(), holder.distance, holder.time);
        holder.name.setText(companyList.get(position).getCompanyDiscout() + "% Off In Store");
        holder.type.setText(companyList.get(position).getCompanyName());
        imageLoader.displayImage(companyList.get(position).getCompanyLogo(), holder.logo);
        imageLoader.displayImage(getCategoryImage(companyList.get(position).getCompanyType()), holder.category);


    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView name;
    TextView type;
    ImageView logo;
    ImageView category;
    TextView distance;
    TextView time;
}
```

If I do the set functions outside of the if, all the images keep reloading and weird things happen (for instance, an already loaded image will reload with a different image if I scroll a page up).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you double-checked your item data (like `Array` or `ArrayList`)? Coz basically what an adapter does is just to display your item data to the assigned listview.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the part of your code that links data to views outside of the if-statement.

ListView items are recycled.  Meaning as you scroll, the listview item that was holding data from row #1 might now be used to show row #10.  This recycled view is sent to getView, and since it is not null it skips the part of your code where you link your data to the view elements.  Unless you write over what is currently there, it will continue showing the data from row #1 (or whatever row it was previously assigned to).

Thus, you want to move the part of your code that links data to views outside of the if-statement.

```
ViewHolder holder;
if (convertView == null)
{
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.tile_company, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.companyname);
    holder.type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.companytype);
    holder.logo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
    holder.category = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category);
    holder.distance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.distance);
    holder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);

    convertView.setTag(holder);

}
else
{
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

    //I moved this block out of your if-statement

    new GetDistanceTime().execute(LocateOutlets.userLatlng, companyList.get(position).getCompanyLatLng(), holder.distance, holder.time);
    holder.name.setText(companyList.get(position).getCompanyDiscout() + "% Off In Store");
    holder.type.setText(companyList.get(position).getCompanyName());
    imageLoader.displayImage(companyList.get(position).getCompanyLogo(), holder.logo);
    imageLoader.displayImage(getCategoryImage(companyList.get(position).getCompanyType()), holder.category);
```

Comment: The problem comes when I use the Universal Image Loader. If I use it outside the if, if keeps reloading the wrong images into my imageviews when I scroll up or down the list.

Comment: Is your image loader asynchronous? Try scrolling super slowly (waiting for each image to fully load before showing the next row) and see if the correct image loads.  Let me know results.